# If I set my iPhone app to include a Facebook login, can I access information about which Facebook groups users are involved in?

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, mobile-development

I want to set it up so users can invite their Facebook friends to join my social media app.  Broadly speaking, the app lets users create groups of their friends.  It would make things much easier for users if, when they're creating their groups and inviting friends to join, they could see a list of the Facebook groups that they're in and invite friends from within those, rather than just from a list of their Facebook friends in general.

Is this something that one can do with the Facebook APIs as they exist currently, or is it even possible to do?  Is this information that Facebook would allow me to have? If you were trying to do this sort of integration, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: I was able to find this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

Comment: No that is not possible